# (ssg-wsg) Authorize end point

Tags: endpoint

I can't find detail about authorization endpoint for this api on ssg-wsg website.

Could you provide, the url for Authorization Endpoint for the ssg-wsg API:?

Comment: try find here https://developer.ssg-wsg.sg/webapp/guides/1em38OkeU0Lmn7Vb6arMN7

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to call consent based APIs?

There is a guide here that is referencing authorization URLs for consent based APIs:
https://developer.ssg-wsg.sg/webapp/guides/6BDCEHkqNKpazwYJQfnz3l

However, for other kinds of APIs, it would seem like authorization URLs are not needed for OAuth APIs - you just need the Client Credentials for authorization.
https://developer.ssg-wsg.sg/webapp/guides/6gvz7gEnwU2dSIKPrTcXnq

It would be good if you could share more details on the issue that you are facing.